# Mockito - Function calls other function, should I mock both?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a code with two methods. Method A is calling method B. Should I mock method B? Or can I let method A call method B since there it's only buciness logic without datatabase connection or httprequests?

```
    public Response InsertAsset(UpdateRequest apiRequest, String token) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{   
    /* TODO
     * Change hard-coded URL implementation
     */
    String url = "http://test:8080/update";

    User user = userRepository.findByToken(token);

    UpdateRequestRequest = new UpdateRequest();

    generateRequestAPI(Request, user);

    Request.setAsset(apiRequest.getAsset());
    Request.setKey(generateCombinedKey(Request, user));

    // Will throw NullPointerException in case HTTP body cannot be generated
    HttpRequest httpRequest = generateHttpPostRequest(url, Request, token);

    HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

    return objectMapper.readValue(httpResponse.body(), Response.class);
}
```

Comment: add your code, please.

Comment: It is unfortunately not clear what your scenario looks like. Please add at least the code examples, reduced to the important aspects!

Comment: @Amadán I added My code.

Comment: @Renato I added the code.

Comment: @MYil Thans! I still do not understand what your methods A and B are.

Comment: @Amadán Thank you for your response. "InsertAsset" is method A, it's using "generateHttpPostRequest" that is method B.

Comment: @MYil Okay, please edit your question to correctly refer to those two methods and clearify, what is your system under test! Also: by Java coding convention method names start with a lower case letter. I also now see that I may have gotten your question wrong before ... :-P

Answer (score 0):

```
Edited because I had gotten the question wrong at first.
```

Short answer is: you may probably just use the `generateHttpPostRequest()`.

Longer answer ...

**The original answer:**

Without knowing your code an answer is impossible. Mocks are for unit tests. In a unit test you have the *system under test* (SUT) and external *dependencies*. For a unit test you want to get rid of all behaviour in the dependecies and instead completely control what you SUT will see during the test. Also unit tests *must* be easy to read, hence complex configurations are a no.

Some hints for your decision:

1. *Never* mock the SUT!
2. If the dependency has no behaviour and you can easily determin what state it will present your SUT, you may not need to mock it.
3. Configuring a mock to return a mock may be needed sometimes but generally should be avoided, if possible.